# Using DFS to do Postorder printing

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list, postorder

I have a graph created from an adjacency list, I am trying to somehow make the DFS also print out the postorder of the graph. Does anyone have suggestions on how I could do this in the DFS function? thank you very much

**sample input:**

```
create 6  
insert 0 3 0  
insert 0 1 0  
insert 1 3 0  
insert 1 2 0  
insert 2 1 0  
insert 3 5 0  
insert 3 4 0  
insert 3 2 0  
insert 4 2 0  
insert 5 2 0  
DFS 0
```

**CODE:**

**main.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
#include "graph.h"

//Main Function 
int main(){

string command,command1;
int src,dest,wght,start,size;


cout << "graph>";
    cin>>command; 
    if(command=="create")
    cin>>size;
    graph A(size);  //initial class instance


//handles all I/O
  do{           
        cout << "graph>";
        cin >> command;

        //Creates an array of size "size" for nodes to be added too
        //if(command == "create"){

            //cin>>size;
            //resize(size);

        //}
        //Tests for user insertion of node
        if (command == "insert"){

            cin >> src >> dest >> wght;
            if(src <= size && dest <= size){
                A.insert(src, dest, wght);
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Error! Node does not exist!"<<endl;
            }
        }

        //Tests for user removal of node
        else if(command == "remove"){

            cin >> src >> dest;
            if(src <= size && dest <= size){
                A.remove(src, dest);
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Error! Node does not exist!"<<endl;
            }
        }

        //Tests for user printing of graph
        else if(command == "DFS"){
            cin >> start;
            A.DFS(start);     
        }

        //Tests for user printing of graph
        else if(command == "print"){
            A.print();     
        }

        else{
            if(command != "quit")
                cout<<"Error! Command not supported."<<endl;
        }

    }while(command != "quit" );

 return 0;
}
```

**graph.h**

```
//graph class file
using namespace std;
#include "node.h"

class graph{
    private:
        int h,f;
        int state[30];
        int counter[30];
        class alist* array;
    public:

        //Initializes the Graph and fills it with NULLs
        graph(int h){
            this->h = h;
            array = new alist [h];
            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
                array[i].head = NULL;
        }

        //Creates a new node by calling instance newlist of listnode
        listnode* newlist(int dest){
            listnode* newnode = new listnode;
                newnode->dest = dest;
                    newnode->next = NULL;
            return newnode;
        }

        //Connects the node of the Graph
        void insert(int src, int dest, int weight){

            listnode* newnode = newlist(dest); 
    newnode->next = array[src].head; 
        newnode->weight = weight; 
            array[src].head = newnode;  
                newnode = newlist(src); 
                    newnode->next = array[dest].head;

        }

        //Removes a node from the graph
        void remove(int srcr, int destr){

            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i){

                listnode* move = array[i].head;
                while (move){
                    if(destr == move->dest){
                        if(srcr==i)
                            array[i].head = NULL;
                    }
                move = move->next;
                }                 
            }
        }

        //Prints the Graph      
        void print(){

            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i){

                listnode* move = array[i].head;
                while (move){
                    cout<<"("<<i <<","<< move->dest<< ","<< move->weight <<")";
                    move = move->next;
                }  
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

        //Traverses the graph using DFS     
        int DFS(int start){
            state[start]=1; //marks the node as visited
            if(start==(h)){ //exits once all nodes have been visited
                return 0;}

                listnode* move = array[start].head;

                    cout<<"Visited "<<start<<endl;

                    if(state[start]!=1){
                        DFS(start);}

                    start++;
                    DFS(start);

        }
};
```

**list.h**

```
//list class file
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

//Adjacency List
class alist
{
    public:
    class listnode *head;
};
```

**node.h**

```
//node class file
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

//Nodes
class listnode
{
    public:
    int dest;
    int weight;
    class listnode* next;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by postorder?

Comment: As in LRV, visit the left nodes, visit the right nodes, visit the origin. So for this graph it would be 2-4-5-3-1-0. I just can't implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not rewrite your own graph class in C++, it is more likely way faster to use boost::graph.

Your DFS implementation seems wrong, you are not iterating all siblings of the node.

Initially, you should init all states to WHITE.
When you first discover a node, you mark is a GRAY. You then recurse the DFS for all
siblings of the node (doing nothing when the node is not marked as WHITE).
Once you have visited all siblings, mark the node as BLACK. At this point, you can
output the index of the node, which will give you the post-order traversal